# Populate drop down list from array using JQuery

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, populate

Assuming I have this array:

```
Array(
      [0] => Array(
                  [Brand] => 'Toyota',
                  [Model] => 'Camry',
                  [Color] => 'Red',
                  [Year] => 2002
      )
      [1] => Array(
                  [brand] => 'Nissan',
                  [Model] => 'Skyline',
                  [Color] => 'White',
                  [Year] => 2005
      )
      [2] => Array(
                  [Brand] => 'Honda',
                  [Model] => 'Civic',
                  [Color] => 'Green',
                  [Year] => 2000
      ) )
```

and then inside a drop down list I have the "keys" Brand + Model + Color + Year

Question: how can I populate another drop down list using JQuery(AJAX), with the "values" when I click on one key?

Example: When I click on **Model**, I want to populate another drop down list with the values **Camry** + **Skyline** + **Civic**, and if I click **Color**, pupulates with **Red** + **White** + **Green** and so on

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If your array is `cars[]` and your select boxes have IDs of "sourceBox" and "targetBox" respectively, the following code will get the text of the selected item in #sourceBox and populate #targetBox with all the equivalent values from your array. So selecting "color" in #sourceBox will populate #targetBox with "red", "white", and "green."

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#sourceBox').change(function(){
        var options = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
          options += '<option>' 
              + cars[i][$('#sourceBox option:selected').text()] 
              + '</option>';
        }
        $('#targetBox').html(options);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the array is in PHP, not Java Script.
How can I parse one array in PHP to one array in Java Script?

Comment: @Derick Check my answer. You can parse PHP array to JS easily. Just use <?php ?> tags inside <script> </script> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just a very general piece of code. You should be more specific (show HTML you want created from that PHP array). Anyways here it goes. This will just create JS arrays with values from your PHP array. It should be easy to work with those then:

```
<?php

$brands = array();
$models = array();
$colors = array();
$years = array();
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
    switch ($k) {
        case 'Brand':
            $brands[] = $v;
            break;
        case 'Model':
            $models[] = $v;
            break;
        case 'Color':
            $colors[] = $v;
            break;
        case 'Years':
            $years[] = $v;
            break;
    }
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

    var brands = new Array(<?php echo count($brands); ?>);
    var models = new Array(<?php echo count($models); ?>);
    var colors = new Array(<?php echo count($colors); ?>);
    var years = new Array(<?php echo count($years); ?>);

<?php

$i = 0;
foreach ($brands as $v) {
    echo 'brands[' . $i. '] = ' . $v . ';'
    ++$i;
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($models as $v) {
    echo 'models[' . $i. '] = ' . $v . ';'
    ++$i;
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($colors as $v) {
    echo 'colors[' . $i. '] = ' . $v . ';'
    ++$i;
}$i = 0;
foreach ($years as $v) {
    echo 'brands[' . $i. '] = ' . $v . ';'
    ++$i;
}

?>

    // now you should have items from your PHP array in JS arrays so you can do something with them

    $('a.populate-brands').click(function() {
        for (v in brands) {
            //
        } 
    })

});    //-->
</script>
```